# How to solve $T(n) = 5T(n-1)+6T(n-2)$ iterative solution

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

$n≥2 , T(0)=1, T(1)=4$

$T(n) =  5T(n-1)+6T(n-2)$

$T(n)$= General rule and
$O(n)$ = Big $O$ notation

$T(n)=?$

$O(n)=?$

I tried to use the information provided.

$T(2) = 5.4 + 6.1=26$

$T(3) = 5.26 + 6.4 = 154$

$T(4) = 5.154 + 6.26 = 926$

$T(n) = ...............?$

How do I create the pattern?(Please don't tell me to study this again. I tried and failed.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is $O(n)$?

Comment: T(n)= general rule, O(n) = Big o notation

Comment: Ah, so by $O(n)$ you mean that you want a function $g$, selected from some class of functions which you like better than others, such that $T(n)=O(g(n))$?

Comment: Yes, after finding the T(n) rule, the Big o notation of this rule will be found

Comment: There are many ways to do this, you may use characteristic equations. Another popular way would be using generating functions.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an specific method to solve this. If you want more information about this topic this equation is called a linear recurence equation (they can be solved in many different methods, and I think it is a nice subject to study).
Since $T(n) =  5T(n-1)+6T(n-2)$ we can find the characteristic polynomial of the recurence which is $x^2-5x-6$. This polynomial has roots $x=-1,6$, so the general term is:
$$T(n)=a(-1)^n+b6^n$$
With the initial conditions T(0)=1, T(1)=4 we can find the values of $a$ and $b$:
$$a+b=1$$
$$-a+6b=4$$
This gives us $a=\frac{2}{7}$ and $b=\frac{5}{7}$ and hence:
$$T(n)=\frac{2}{7}(-1)^n+\frac{5}{7}6^n$$

From this, one gets that: $$O(n)=\frac{5}{7}6^n$$ (I am not sure if this is what you want as $O(n)$)

Comment: I will work on this topic. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Thanks. If you deem my answer being the right one please tick it as such so that it gets a green ✅

Comment: Hello, could you please tell me how you found the equation x2−5x−6=0?

Comment: You take all the terms of the relation to the LHS, then the coefficients of the quadratic are the coefficients of the $T_n, T_{n-1}, T_{n-2}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would like to ask a second question. How do we place the sign at the beginning of the coefficients in the equation x2−5x−6=0? (For example -5x,-6)

Comment: Is what you get when you take all terms to the left: $T(n) -5T(n-1)-6T(n-2)=0$

Answer (score 0):

The general method to solve this kind of recurrence is to replace $T_n=r^n$:

$$r^n-5r^{n-1}-6r^{n-2}=0\rightarrow r^2-5r-6=0$$

with the roots $$r_1=6, r_2=-1,$$  and the general term is:

$T_n=A6^n+B(-1)^n$, with $T_0=1, T_1=4$.

So we have to solve the system:

$A+B=1$

$6A-B=4\rightarrow A=\frac{5}{7}, B=\frac{2}{7}\rightarrow$

$T_n=\frac{5\cdot6^n+2(-1)^n}{7}$